# ArrayAdapter stock filtering showing wrong elements

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have extended ArrayAdapter for my custom class. My class overrides `toString()` and returns the field which i want to use for search queries.

This is my filter code:

`productItemAdapter.getFilter().filter(filterText.toLowerCase());`

this is my `toString()` code:

`return name.toLowerCase();`

Filtering is working (the correct number of elements is returned), but it's the wrong elements. It always shows the the first elements on the list instead of the ones that match the search...

Comment: Don't be afraid to post your adapter's code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and I would assume (like me) that you didn't read the documentation when trying to implement this.

I was passing in my array of objects to the ArrayAdapter and subsequently passing the array onto the super constructor.

The mistake I made was: I stored a reference to the passed in array and used **that** array to draw the items in the `getView()` method:

```
 public SimpleAdapter( Context context, List< MyType > values )
 {
    super( context, R.layout.rowlayout, values );
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
 }

  @Override
  public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
  {
    // ...
    MyType myType = values.get( position );
    // ...
  }
```

What I **should** have done is called `getItem()` on the ArrayAdapter class e.g.

```
  MyType myType = getItem( position );
```

Which fixed it beautifully and in hindsight is pretty obvious.

-(e)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Works when implementing custom adapter extending ArrayAdapter and using SearchView to do filtering.